# Best Polar Pattern and dB setting for VO?

Tags: voice-over, recording

Hey everyone,

I have a Neumann microphone (can't mind the model!) and on the mike you can choose the polar patterns . . .I assume that Cardioid is best for recording some VO?

There are also other options such as a little slider which has -dB values on it. I'm unsure what exactly these do or what they can add to the recording?

Sorry for sounding a bit silly but I'm really stumped when it comes to how things work outside of actually dubbing and mixing!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Aaron,

First of all:
I don't want to sound harsh, but these are very basic things anyone, that has dubbing/mixing experience, should be able to understand if he or she steps into a studio.

Questions:
1. Did you get a manual or can you look it up on google? You'll need the model number.
2.If you do dubbing and mixing, don't you know some people that can help you out?

Arnoud

Edit:
Ok that did sound a bit harsh, let me give you some quick and dirty answers:
The polar pattern allows you to choose between several patterns, like:
Omni: most natural sounding, records everything around the microphone, not a typical VO setting because room acoustics will be picked up also.
Cardiod: More focused soundfield to where the mic is pointing (there's a front and back to a mic, figure that out first). Usefull for VO, first choice with a mic in a reflective room.
Figure 8: Special pattern, google it, can be used for VO, not first choice in my opinion.

Level/dB switch: allows you to attenuate the level from the capsule before it goes into the preamp. Prevents distortion with loud screaming. Not very useful for VO.

Sometimes there's a freq filter: useful to attenuate low frequencies, not especially necessary for a VO unless there's a lot of low end rumble from adjacent traffic or machinery that distorts the preamp.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Arnoud, 

Thanks for that. I am aware of what polar patterns are - I was just unsure which I should use if I'm recording a VO and if Cardioid was correct. 

The level/dB switch I didn't really understand so will just keep that at 0 based on what you said.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ah ok! Good luck!